# Summation of data, linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to summarize the "count" field where "Room" and "object code" are equal.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea how is your context set, what is the table name and dozen other things that are necessary to answer your question, but it will definitely use `GroupBy` LINQ method, something like:

```
var results = db.TableName.GroupBy(x => new { x.Room, x.ObjectCode })
                          .Select(g => new { g.Key.Room, g.Key.ObjectCode, Count = g.Sum(x => x.Code) })
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Works great. Sorry for my sloppy question.